# How to initialize a map's keys first in Typescript for a React state variable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have a state variable that maps a string user name to a UserData object. We have the usernames initially in the string array 'users'.

> Is there a way to set the initial state of 'userDataMap' to have the
> keys from 'users' and to fill in the UserData values later?

```
  export const MyComponent: React.FC<Props> = props => {
    // string array
    const users = getUsernames();

    // maps a user name to a UserData object
    const [userDataMap, setUserDataMap] = React.useState<Map<string, UserData>>(new Map());
    
    // try to have userDataMap keys set to 'users' at start, add UserData values later

    return ();
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `getUsernames` is a synchronous function (i.e. doesn't return a `Promise`; appears to be synchronous with how you use it), you can do it in the `useState` initializer function:

```js
const [userDataMap, setUserDataMap] = React.useState<Map<string, UserData>>(() => {
  const map = new Map();
  for (const username of getUsernames()) {
    map.set(username, undefined);
  }
  return map;
});
```

If you use the `users` variable somewhere else in the code, then do what you have for that section instead of calling `getUsernames()` inside of the initializer.

If `getUsernames` is asynchronous, I can add additional code for that.